# Use LXML on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, lxml, aws-lambda

I am trying to run a program in AWS lambda with the lxml import. However I get this error in the lambda console every time:

```
Unable to import module 'scraper': /var/task/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

I have uploaded the lxml files in the deployment package to Lambda as I have with every other working function, however lxml will not import properly.

Comment: Are you bundling the lxml system level requirements? http://lxml.de/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue. 
As @Erik said, you'll have to bundle any shared library you need.

You have 2 options :

1. Compile the libraries yourself on an EC2 instance (follow [this guide](http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html))
2. Use someone elses precompiled binaries (https://github.com/cjpetrus/lambda-lxml-base)