# How to import lxml from precompiled binary on AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lxml

I'm trying to import the `lxml` library in Python to execute an AWS Lambda function but I'm getting the following error: `[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lxml'`. To solve this, I followed the recommendation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387664/use-lxml-on-aws-lambda) SO answer and used precompiled binaries from the following [repo](https://github.com/cjpetrus/lambda-lxml-base).

I used the `lxml_amazon_binaries.zip` file from that repo, which has this structure:

```
 lxml_amazon_binaries
    ├── lxml
    └── usr
```

I uploaded the entire `zip` file to an AWS Lambda layer, created a new Lambda function, and tested with a simple `from lxml import etree`, which led to the above error.

**Am I uploading/using these binaries correctly?** I'm not sure what caused the error. Using different Python runtimes didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most reliable way to create `lxml` layer is using Docker as explain in the [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/). Specifically, the **verified** steps are (executed on Linux, but windows should also work as long as you have Docker):

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
lxml
```

3. Run the following docker command:

The command will create layer for python3.8:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Archive the layer as zip:

```
zip -9 -r mylayer.zip python
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtime` to `python3.8`.
6. Add the the layer created in step 5 to your function.
7. I tested the layer using your code:

```
from lxml import etree

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    root = etree.Element("root")
    root.append( etree.Element("child1") )
    print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

It  works **correctly**:

```
b'<root>\n  <child1/>\n</root>\n'
```

Comment: For python3.9:

docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/; exit"